# Fatal error in launcher, pip is wrong on install

Tags: python, pip, path

I recently cleaned up all the different python versions I have. Now somehow my pip is failing even after a forced reinstall:

```
C:\Python311\Scripts>python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 23.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-23.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-23.1.2
  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.10.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\-username-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-23.1.2

C:\Python311\Scripts>pip list
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python311\python.exe"  "C:\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe" list': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I know that environment variables are not to blame:

```
echo %PATH%
C:\Users\-myusername-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\;C:\Python311\Scripts\;

C:\Python311\Scripts>dir | findstr /i "pip"
11/25/2022  11:22 PM           108,382 pip.exe
11/25/2022  11:22 PM           108,382 pip3.10.exe
11/25/2022  11:22 PM           108,382 pip3.11.exe
11/25/2022  11:22 PM           108,382 pip3.exe
```

I'm fresh out of ideas. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You're mixing up environments of Python 3.10 and 3.11 by installing pip for Python 3.11 with PYTHONPATH likely prioritizing Python 3.10.

Comment: But I don't have python 3.11 installed. I've verified that in the `Add and Remove Programs` list.